# Responsive Image Slider With Caption and 100% width and Custom height

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have a task where i need to display an Image slider with Some text caption which i write in each image and jquery animation fading effect.The slider should be 100% in width for all screen size and it should take the custom height of the image.
Believe me i tried whole day to get the good solution but did not found any plugin Which will full fill my requirement.The solution i was getting was like they dont have the width and height compatibility and others with Transition animation effect.

Please help me to get the solution.Any links to direct me will be great start for me.

Comment: Show us some of this effort that you say you put in... share what you used that got you close to what you were trying to achieve and we can help you tweak it.

Comment: @JRulle http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/pvxa4trb/38/ Please refer my fiddle link.In this link i have to fix the height of the image slider conatiner to `860px;` and remove the extra white space (gap) in the subsequent down side Divs .If you can help me in this.You will be a life savior.I tried my best but was not able to crack it.

Comment: @JRulle Please help me in this bro.. You will be a life savior ..Please please

Comment: Your issue is that the slider is setting the height of .slides before the first image is fully loaded (i.e. the slider has no idea how tall the image is yet).

Comment: @JRulle So how can we fix the height to `860px;` So that slider can know the height before fixing it ...

Comment: The problem is actually much larger than that... the `<li>` elements get absolutely positioned in order to facilitate the fade in/out effect. This causes them to be out of the document flow and methods of dynamic sizing like `height: auto` and `overflow` essentially ignore these elements. Fixing this would require more time that I have to offer... sorry.

Comment: @JRulle please help me i have spend my whole day but end up in frustation only .thats why i posted this known silly question on SO ..my all hope is you bro..please help me

Comment: Did myanswer below make sense?

Comment: @JRulle thank u very much for your answer.i an not accessible to system now.will check nd mark as answer.thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative slider - much easier to use.
http://bxslider.com/

And here is a **[demo in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/sm0x02q5/)** that you can reference, it meets the same specs as your original with less overhead and much. I even set up your description divs.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
      <img src="http://image-ling-goes-here.jpg" />
      <div class="slide-desc">
        <h2>Slider Title 1</h2>
        <p>description text... <a class="more" href="#">more</a></p>
      </div>
  </li>
// more slides go here
</ul>
```

Here is the super simple Jquery to set up the slider ([link to all config options](http://bxslider.com/options)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
        mode: 'fade',
        adaptiveHeight: 'true'
    });
});
```

Make sure you follow the insructions and download/include references to the relevant JQuery libraries as well as the bx-slider library and css in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

*The styles i included in the fiddle are below with explanations of what they do:*

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; } //removes silly body margin
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport { border: none; left: 0; } //removes the bxslider 'polaroid-style' frame
ul.bxslider { margin: 0; padding: 0; } //fixes an alignment issues that crept in when the mode was set to fade
div.slide-desc { position: absolute; bottom: 5px; left: 50px; right: 50px; } //aligns your description block
```